# Inverse of a 'Pure Translation' Homogenous Transformation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse

I have been able to compute the inverse of a homogenous transformation matrix for pure translation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$):

$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & a \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & b \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & c \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} \right]^{-1}=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -a \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -b \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -c \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} \right]
$

I computed this inverse using the formula $\text{adj}(A)/\text{det}(A)$ (where $A$ is an invertible square matrix).

Is there a way to compute the inverse of this matrix without using this formula?

Comment: It's fairly easy to compute the inverse via row operations, i.e. by row-reducing the matrix $[A|I] \leadsto [I|A^{-1}]$

Comment: If we were to generalize the problem to finding the inverse of a pure translation homogenous transformation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n $, could we still use row operations to find the inverse?

Comment: Yes, in exactly the same way.

Comment: By realizing that the operation is equivalent to $x\rightarrow x+v$, then clearly the inverse is  $x\rightarrow x-v$

Comment: Are you referring to row operations?  Could you be more specific?

Comment: I am referring to the matrix operation on a vector.